# Nodejs Redis - before expires event

Tags: redis, node-redis

i have a redis subscriber to do something when an expiration event occur.
When the expire event occur, the key's parameters are deleted;
there is some kind of event to take these parameters just before the expire? Like a pre-expire event.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ATM there isn't. The way to "work around" this, if you really need that kind of fine level control, is stop using the built-in expiration and replace it with your own homegrown code that manages it.